# Why would eclipse not show search results inside file in results list?

Tags: eclipse, search

We have **one installation of Eclipse** which does not show the individual lines on which search results occur as do all other installations, as shown here:

[image]

**How can we turn on this feature so that individual results in each line are shown?**

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a question of what tool you are using.  If you do a text search, you get one line per hit.  But if, say, you look for references to a Java method, you get one line per file.

Although it seems like a perfectly desirable thing, I can't find any way to get Java search to return one line per hit.

Answer (score 1):

In the preferences of the Search window (usually button with triangle icon) choose "Show as List" item

Comment: doesn't work. Java Search results are still displayed one line per method.

Comment: The line number will not be displayed